# Constructor initialization of built-in types

Tags: c++, gcc

So I'm currently reading through "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup (great book), and it mentions in section 17.3.1 that an object without a defined constructor and that is initialized without an initializer, will (in non-static cases) leave built-in types undefined.

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int id;
    // No constructor defined,
    // so default constructor generated
};

void f() {
    A a; // No initializer
    std::cout << a.id << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect garbage to be printed when I run this code, but instead I get an initialized (`0`) value for `a.id`. Additionally, if we redefine `A` to be:

```
class A {
public:
    int id;
    A()=default;
};
```

Now when I run this code, `a.id` will be garbage values, as I had expected previously.

For the first case, why is the `id` member of A being initialized? Why are the two cases resulting in different results?

I am using g++/gcc version 8.1.0

Comment: "Undefined behaviour", like using an undefined value, means anything can happen, including boring things like getting zero.

Comment: Seeing a 0 value does not mean that `a.id` is being initialized. What you're seeing is leftover stuff; sometimes it seems to make sense, but it's garbage, nonetheless.

Comment: See [what is undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939)

Answer (score 2):

> but instead I get an initialized (0) value for `a.id`

Just because the value happens to be 0 doesn't mean it's initialized.   Reading an uninitialized value is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so the output can be anything, including 0.

If I run this same code on my system, I get the following output:

```
791621423
```

Answer (score 0):

> For the first case, why is the id member of A being initialized? Why
>   are the two cases resulting in different results?

```
A a; // No initializer
```

`a` is uninitialized which will have *indeterminate value*.

As per [dcl.init/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#12)

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   *default-initialized*. When storage for an object with **automatic** or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate
>   value**, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced.

Using variables with indeterminate values is *undefined behavior*.

```
std::cout << a.id << std::endl; // undefined behavior for a.id
```

Thus, resulting to different values in different cases.